# FluentNHibernate exception when there are slash in the default value

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have been trying to map a string value using FulentNHibernate like below.

```
 Map(x => x.FilePath).Length(500).Not.Nullable().Default(@"C:\Program Files\server\data\conf\groups.txt");
```

But this gives an error. If I add text without slashes it works. Is there a specific way to add text with slashes? I have also tried double slashes.

Comment: Have you also tried using forward slashes ('/')?

Comment: It needs to be a backward slash since it is a file path

Comment: As long as the path is used in .NET forward slashes work fine in filepaths.

Comment: I checked it doesn't allow forward slashes as well

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the correct way to put it. Note the additional quotes without them it won't work

```
 Map(x => x.FilePath).Length(500).Not.Nullable().Default("\"\'C:\\Program Files\\server\\data\\conf\\groups.txt\'\"");
```